# Logger not working inside AsyncCallback

Tags: gwt, junit

I have a problem with logging with GWT Unit testing:

```
logInfo("Creating Stuff: " + stuffAutoBeanSerializer.encodeData(stuff)); // Logging works and showing in the IntelliJ console

myService.createStuff(stuff, new AsyncCallback<Stuff>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                logSevere(throwable.getMessage()); // Not showing in the console
            }
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Stuff stuff) {
                logInfo("Created Stuff: " + stuffAutoBeanSerializer.encodeData(stuff)); // not showing in the console
            }
});
```

Even though the request is an `onSuccess` since data is stored in the database. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of your test method is missing, but the problem is almost certainly that you didn't tell the test case that it was async, so when the method returned without an exception, the test infrastructure assumed that the test passed.

In an async GWTTestCase, you *must* use `delayTestFinish(millis)` to indicate that the test won't be done when it returns, and then `finishTest()` (probably in your onSuccess) to indicate that the test passed. If `finishTest()` is not called in time (or at all), the test will be assumed to have failed.